# Getting emails from imap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imap

I'm trying to connect to a imap server to get the emails and i'm using this

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('example.com')
```

this creates an imap instance. But when i'm trying to authenticate using

```
imap.authenticate('LOGIN', 'username', 'password')
```

I get `Plaintext authentication disallowed on non-secure (SSL/TLS) connections`.
In the imap instance class i've seen that CAPABILITY property contains this

> LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED

and instead of LOGIN I've used STARTTLS but this seems to be unknown type.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this but if you want plain text authentication just enable SSL:

```rb
imap = Net::IMAP.new('example.com', { ssl: true })
```

EDIT: That assumes that you are actually using SSL configuration and port for SSL IMAP.